# SQL query giving wrong result on linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to pull user data from 2 tables, one locally and one on a linked server, but I get the wrong results when querying the remote server.

I've cut my query down to

```
select * from SQL2.USER.dbo.people where persId = 475785
```

for testing and found that when I run it I get no results even though I know the person exists.
(persId is an integer, db is SQL Server 2000 and dbo.people is a table by the way)

If I copy/ paste the query and run it on the same server as the database then it works.

It only seems to affect certain user ids as running for example

```
select * from SQL2.USER.dbo.people where persId = 475784
```

works fine for the user before the one I want.

Strangely I've found that

```
select * from SQL2.USER.dbo.people where persId like '475785'
```

also works but

```
select * from SQL2.USER.dbo.people where persId > 475784
```

brings back records with persIds starting at 22519 not 475785 as I'd expect.

Hope that made sense to somebody

Any ideas ?

UPDATE:
Due to internal concerns about doing any changes to the live people table, I've temporarily moved my database so they're both on the same server and so the linked server issue doesn't apply. Once the whole lot is migrated to a separate cluster I'll be able to investigate properly. I'll update the update once this happens and I can work my way through all the suggestions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is persID an integer on both databases?

Comment: Do you get the same results if you use OPENQUERY instead of 4 part names? It would also be helpful to see of script of your linked server add to see which driver your linked server uses to connect.

Comment: Are both linked servers MS SQL 2000?

Comment: Can you have a look at the answers and suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that LIKE operates is not a major clue: LIKE forces integers to string (so you can say WHERE field LIKE '2%' and you will get all records that start with a 2, even when field is of integer type). Your incorrect comparisons would lead me to think your indexes are corrupt, but you say they work when not used via the link... however, the selected index *might* be different depending on the use? (I seem to recall an instance when I had duplicate indexes and only one was stale, although that was too long ago to recall the exact cause).

Nevertheless, I would try rebuilding your index using the DBCC DBREINDEX (tablenname) command. If it turns out that doing so fixes your query, you may want to rebuild them all: [here is a script](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/rebuilding_indexes_p1.aspx) for rebuilding them all easily.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and let you know what happens. There's a certain amount of paranoia to get past first as it's the db that most of the companys' business depends on so I need to check there's no chance of it damaging anything when the maintenance runs

Comment: Can you make a development copy of the database? I highly recommend testing such an operation on a dev box first: if you do have corrupted indexes, it may be a symptom of something greater, and you are right to avoid making the problem worse.

Answer (score 1):

Is dbo.people a table or a view? I've seen something similar where the underlying table schema had been changed and dropping and recreating the view fixed the problem, although the fact that the query works if run directly on the linked server does indicate something index based..

Comment: I've encountered the bug that Nathan refers to. Showing up in this way is really unlikely, but it is possible. If the view were hiding a the real persId column, and the remote server was holding an obsolete definition of the view, then this could be the result.

Answer (score 1):

Is the linked server using the same collation? Depending on the index used, I could see something like this perhaps happening if the servers were *not* collation compatible, but the linked server was set up *with* collation compatible (which tells Sql Server it can run the query on the remote server).

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following:

- Check your definition on the linked server, and confirm that SQL2 is the
  server you expect it to be
- Check and compare the execution plans both from the remote and local servers
- Try linking by IP address rather than name, to ensure you have the proper machine
- Put the code into a stored procedure on the remote machine, and try calling that instead

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug to me - I;ve read of some issues along these lines, btu can't remember specifically what.  What version of SQL Server are you running?

```
select * from SQL2.USER.dbo.people where persId = 475785
```

for a PersID which fails how does:

```
SELECT *
FROM OpenQuery(SQL2, 'SELECT * FROM USER.dbo.people WHERE persId = 475785')
```

behave?